# Looking to make archive.php display in two columns for Wordpress site

Tags: php, wordpress, archive

Very new Wordpress apprentice here. Trying to get my archive page to display posts in two columns going like:

Post 1 Post 2

Post 3 Post 4

Here is an example from a figma we were working on: https://ibb.co/N3XwtwD

My question is, what code can I add to my files to allow this? I currently have some bootstrap classes on the html portion I inserted here and it is displaying as one column, so I don't know if those classes will interfere with anything. Here is my archive.php code below:

```html
<?php 

get_header();
?>

<div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
        <p class="font-size"><?php the_archive_title(); ?></p>
        <hr>
    </div>

<div class="container">
<?php 
  while(have_posts()) {

    the_post(); ?>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-lg-6">
            <p class="font-size text-center"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></p>
            <img class="img-fluid mb-3"<?php
                        the_post_thumbnail(); 
                                ?>
            <p class="category-font">Published on <?php the_time('n.j.y');?></p>
            <p>Posted by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></p>
        </div>
      </div>
<?php }
echo paginate_links();
?>


  </div>

  <?php
  get_footer();
  ?>
```

First time posting here so apologies if I left anything important out. Really appreciate this place!

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to create a row every two posts and you have to add `<div class="col-lg-6">` two times in a row. check below code.

```
<?php get_header(); ?>

<div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
    <p class="font-size"><?php the_archive_title(); ?></p>
    <hr>
</div>

<div class="container">
    <?php 
    $count = 1;
    while( have_posts() ) { the_post(); 
        if ( $count % 2 == 1){ ?>
            <div class="row">
        <?php } ?>
            <div class="col-lg-6">
                <p class="font-size text-center"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></p>
                <?php the_post_thumbnail(); ?>
                <p class="category-font">Published on <?php the_time('n.j.y');?></p>
                <p>Posted by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></p>
            </div>
        <?php if ( $count % 2 == 0 ){ ?>
            </div>
        <?php } $count++; ?>
    <?php } 
    if ( $count % 2 != 1 ) echo "</div>";
    echo paginate_links(); ?>
</div>
```

Comment: Ahh I think I see what you're saying. Sadly after copying the code over, it didn't work. :(

Comment: You son of a gun! It's displaying as two columns now! All I need to do is add some other css styling and I think I'm good to go. Thank you so much!

Comment: I was looking for a way to do that! Was able to accept the answer, but I need more reputation to upvote haha. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

Please replace with the below code that helps you.

```
<?php
get_header();
?>

<div class="container mt-5 mb-5">
        <p class="font-size"><?php the_archive_title(); ?></p>
        <hr>
    </div>

<div class="container">

<?php 
$counterval = 0;
  while(have_posts()) {
    the_post(); 

    $counterval++;
    if($counterval % 2 != 0)
    { ?>
        <div class="row">
    <?php } ?>
    <div class="col-lg-6">
            <p class="font-size text-center"><a href="<?php the_permalink();?>"><?php the_title();?></a></p>
            <?php $featured_img_url = get_the_post_thumbnail_url(get_the_ID(),'full');
            if(!empty($featured_img_url)){ ?>
                <img class="img-fluid mb-3" src="<?php echo esc_url($featured_img_url); ?>" />
            <?php } ?>            
            <p class="category-font">Published on <?php the_time('n.j.y');?></p>
            <p>Posted by <?php the_author_posts_link() ?></p>
        </div>
    <?php 
    if($counterval % 2 == 0)
    { ?>
    </div>
    <?php } ?>
    
<?php } ?>

<?php echo paginate_links();
?>


  </div>

  <?php
  get_footer();
  ?>
```